# Convert enum to _variant_t C++

Tags: c++, enums, com, typeconverter

I'm writing a COM client. One of the functions in my COM server takes enum as an argument and returns a number (long) Looks like this:

> Function GetFlowsheetStatus(iQueryFlags As FlowSheetObjStatusFlag_enum) As Long
>   I'm using both early and late binding (IDispatch and direct interfaces) So I wrote something like that:FlowSheetObjStatusFlag_enum flag;_variant_t p = _variant_t(flag);

So I need to convert the enum "FlowSheetObjStatusFlag_enum" to _variant_t in order to be able to pass it. How can I do that?

Comment: What makes you think you have to convert it to a variant? Plus the "looks like this" example looks like VBA or VB6, not C++, but you ask for C++; can you clarify?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to pass anything other than variants, HRESULT returns error. The example is from the COM server documentation which is written in VBA..

Comment: With that VBA signature, using Variant is wrong. Unless you're using the library via Automation (calling IDispatch methods), which you didn't mention and is the hard way; or if the example is lying (always possible). Assuming the example is not lying, and this being C++, you can only possibly pass the correct data type or it won't even compile, so I'm confused at "returns error". The correct "enum" definition to pass depends to how you incorporated the type library into your C++ code. If you used #import, for example, examine the generated C++ files to determine the name of the enum type.

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was that I created my own enum type and wanted to pass it through Automation. And I use IDispatch methods. I solved the problem by finding the enum exposed by the Server. My mistake was writing an identical enum for that.

Comment: I'm using both early and late binding (IDispatch and direct interfaces) So I wrote something like that:FlowSheetObjStatusFlag_enum flag;_variant_t p = _variant_t(flag); I still have errors but I think their origins are somewhere else (hopefully)

Comment: I see, that would do it. C++ types don't have structural equivalency: two different types (and enums)  are not equivalent even if they are structurally identical. That fixes the direct interfaces. For IDispatch, it doesn't matter; a Variant cannot contain an enumeration; all you can do is pass the numerical value as an int. That's why you can't use enums in VBScript.

Comment: For the future, all the details you just provided in your comments are absolutely key to understanding the nature of your problem. You need to provide the details of what you are doing - from the start - on the question itself, and exactly what errors you are getting, so that other members can help you out. Otherwise it's a guessing game (like we just played :-) ) and that's not productive for you. Good luck.

Comment: I will make sure to do that in future, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Actually, let me ask you to do something. Please edit the question to add those details, and then post an answer explaining how you fixed it, and accept that answer. This will help future visitors. You don't get points for accepting your own answer, but you help others that might have the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sure will do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I created my own enum type and wanted to pass it through Automation. I solved the problem by finding the enum exposed by the Server. My mistake was writing an identical enum for that. I guess the enum exposed was already compatible since it was originated via the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with COM myself but C++ does allow casting from 1 type to another.

- `static_cast` to cast 1 type to another *compatible* type
  (i.e. `int` to `double`)
- `dynamic_cast` for down casting a base type to a derived type
- `reinterpret_cast` which should **ONLY** be used if you absolutely need to use it. It takes a type and says "Its not this type, instead treat it as this."
  (i.e. `int x = reinterpret_cast<int>(std::string{"my string hello"});`)
- `const_cast` is used mostly to cast *away* const-ness but can be used to give const-ness too. I thought I would list it here anyway for depth.

For more details you should read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast